# Possible reasons for irregularly high query execution time?

Tags: postgresql, performance, write-ahead-logging, postgresql-performance

[image]

The above is a graph showing the average response times per second (including error bars) for an experiment where I simulate 30 clients which are all invoking the same query multiple times. I ran this experiment over and over and over again using also different queries but the result is always that around 20 seconds there is this one peak.

I'm not that familiar with postgres. The only thing that I thought of which could be responsible for this behavior is the vacuum daemon. However I enabled logs for the deamon and it turns out that it's not active at all in the period of the experiment. Is there anything else running at arbitrary points which could cause a high query time for a short period?

The function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_message(_queue_id BIGINT, _source_client_id BIGINT, _receiver_client_id BIGINT, _content TEXT, OUT status SMALLINT) AS $$
    BEGIN
                INSERT INTO message VALUES(DEFAULT, _queue_id, _source_client_id, _receiver_client_id, _content, DEFAULT);
                status = 0;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The respective table:

```
CREATE TABLE message(
    id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('message_id_seq'),
    queue_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    sender_client_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    receiver_client_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    insertion_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(queue_id) REFERENCES queue(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(sender_client_id) REFERENCES client(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(receiver_client_id) REFERENCES client(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Index on the table:

```
CREATE INDEX message_index ON message(queue_id, receiver_client_id, sender_client_id);
```

EDIT: Ran it on AWS. Same pattern. Thus it's no hardware thing.

Comment: did you use the stuff listed in the answer here:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653884/postgres-query-execution-time?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653884/postgres-query-execution-time?rq=1

Comment: I am a [self acclaimed] expert on PG optimisation. And I don't understand the question. period.

Comment: Show us the query.  I have to wonder if Postgres's query optimizer is doing something strange...

Comment: I edited the question and added some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That spike is probably caused by dirty data pages being flushed to disk. Raise the `checkpoint_segments` parameter in the `postgresql.conf` file.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-CHECKPOINTS

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-configuration.html

Comment: I did some experiments and at least so far it seems that WAL is indeed related to the problem (Nb.: I'm so new to this field that I did not even know about WAL). However what I did so far was to decrease rather than increase the checkpoint_segments and I got good results with it (need to do some more experiments thought to confirm). If I understood the documentation correctly then an increase may cause an even higher peak at some later point.Does that make sense?

Comment: @ben That makes sense. The point of raising it is the assumption that the `checkpoint_timeout` will be reached before another unusual high activity period starts. You can spread the IO activity by raising `checkpoint_completion_target` in instead of lowering `checkpoint_segments`. I would probably raise both.

Comment: I see. Btw I set `synchronous_commit` to `off` and the peak was gone completely. Thus again this issue indeed seems to be related completely to WAL. Nb.: Increasing `checkpoint_segments` and/or the timeout or the completion target did not really work in this scenario. I guess it's maybe because the `checkpoint_segments` and `checkpoint_timeout` define a maximum and are not "obligatory" and the load on the system is very high during the experiment.